# How can we add flows in opendaylight using postman

Tags: opendaylight

I am currently working on software defined networking project. I wanted to know how can we add flows using opendaylight controller.

I tried adding flows using opendaylight controller with postman but they are failing due to 405 method not supported Error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are restAPI available to do this task. Go through opendaylight documentation to find restAPI matching your need.

Maybe this [link](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_OpenFlow_Plugin:End_to_End_Flows) would help.

Comment: I am getting 404 Not found .